# Excel VBA - comportamento estranho!

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Comportamento estranho no VBA Excel!
O código abre um arquivo de origem, e copia uma Tabela existente.
Cola a Tabela em um arquivo destino - na planilha APOIO - e fecha o arquivo de origem.
No arquivo destino há uma planilha de nome ALUGUEL, onde retorno os dados da planilha APOIO - somente alguns dados.
Antes de manipular os dados na planilha ALUGUEL, o comando Cells.Clear limpa os dados desta planilha - ALUGUEL, para poder colar novos dados:

```
wsDestino.Range("A3:Z500").Clear
```

Os dados anteriores, é claro, foram completamente deletados, inclusive a formatação, onde foi inserida também uma formatação linha a linha com cor sim e cor não, usando:

```
wsDestino.Range(Cells(lgLoopLin, "A"), Cells(lgLoopLin, lgUltCol)).Interior.Color = RGB(198, 224, 180)
```

Até aí tudo bem.
Tudo funciona normalmente.

Mas se eu desproteger a planilha ALUGUEL, selecionar os dados, deletar com a tecla DELETE, e no ícone Cor Do Preenchimento escolher Sem Preenchimento, e acionar a macro, dá o erro "O Excel parou de funcionar".
Interessante que se eu selecionar os dados e apagar tudo manualmente no ícone Limpar/LimparTudo, o erro não acontece.
Ficou a impressão de que, por ter usado manualmente Cor Do Preenchimento/Sem Preenchimento, este procedimento faz com que aconteça o erro.

Claro que a intenção é não apagar manualmente.
Apaguei os dados manualmente somente para teste.
Detalhe: utilizo o Application.ScreenUpdate no início como False, habilitando novamente no final como True.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Nunca tive este erro, mas tente [desabilitar o JIT debugging](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/visualstudio/debugger/just-in-time-debugging-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2015) ou leia [esta ref](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista/just-in-time-debugging-error-box-opens/9f606f8a-3529-458a-80af-a3545a5c7570). Você possui o Visual Studio instalado?

Comment: Visual Studio instalado: 2012.
Mas não faço uso dele.
O mais interessante é que acontece da forma que postei.
Quando aplico a macro ela segue normalmente.

Comment: E se eu deletar manualmente, o que não é o correto pois a macro já faz isso, mas deletando usando o ícone Limpar/LimparTudo,a macro corre normalmente.
Achei interessante a macro fazer o que ele se propõe, e somente limpando da forma que mencionei no post é que acontece o erro.
Lembrando novamente: NÃO será usado a limpeza dos dados manualmente, pois a macro já faz isso.